# Logrotate not rotating file after file size exceeds the limit.

Tags: logrotate, log-rotation

From logrotate manpage.

> It will not modify a log more than once in one day unless the criterion for that log is based on the log's
>          size

According to the man page, logrotate should rotate file if the configuration is based on logs size. But, my file is not getting even if the filesize if greater than 100k.

Can somebody point out what is the issue.

My configuration

```
/home/jetech/work/lampstack-5.3.9-0/apache2/logs/access_log  {
    copytruncate
    compress
#    dateext
    rotate 365
    size 100k
    olddir /home/jetech/work/lampstack-5.3.9-0/apache2/old_logs
    notifempty
    nomail
    missingok
}
```

Comment: Pls check the `cron` command: [cron how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**How do you know the file is not getting rotated?**

On a Debian 6 Linode I have, in the default configuration `logrotate` was only scheduled by `cron` to run once per day, and at a very odd time at that.  If only run once per day, naturally it'll only have one opportunity per day to look at the configuration, do the comparisons and perform the rotations required.

So, are you sure you're actually running your logrotate?  Might want to check your `/etc/cron*` and `/etc/cron*/*` to see when and how often logrotate is scheduled to run.

For example, if `logrotate` script is present in `/etc/cron.daily`, then you may want to move it to `/etc/cron.hourly`, or, if hourly is not good enough, create a file in `/etc/cron.d/` with the following content, to run `logrotate` every 10 minutes:

```
*/10  *  *  *  *   root    /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Comment: Thank you this did help. I copy paste the /etc/cron.daily/logrorate to /etc/cron.hourly/logrorate

It really help a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: Copy & paste may run it twice; you may want to move it, instead, using `mv`

Answer (score 0):

So `logrotate` actually works like this,

- In the configuration we specify a running frequency (*daily*, *hourly*, *monthtly*)
- There is an entry in `/etc/cron.xxx` for *logrotate* to execute.
- *logrotate* runs via *crontab*

if you mentioned *daily*, everyday at the specified amount of time (/etc/crontab), the crontab process will run *logrotate* process for rotation.
So, file size limit will not work as the process will never run.